# How to create a function with string argument without using quotations marks every time?

Tags: python, function, arguments

I am creating a Python program using:

```
def arena(type = 'c'):
   if type == 'c':
       #do some stuff
   elif type == 'd':
       #do other stuff
   else:
       #do different stuff
```

However, I am lazy and would prefer to type `arena(c)` not `arena('c')` into the interactive shell to call forth the function actions. Is there a way to do this? How?

I was just using `0`,`1`,`2` before but having it use letters is easier to remember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes just set a variable named c with:

```
c='c'
```

Then call like:

```
arena(c)
```

Without quotes a value represent a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your main function to a class

```
class arena:
    def c():
        print('stuff')
    def d():
        print('stuff2')
    def e():
        print('stuffe')
```

then you can call it with

```
arena.c()
```